# Closeness with spouse/family among the Trimurti

Tags: marriage, shakti, trinity, family, iconography

I am asking this question purely on a pictorial stance.
Lord Brahma (And Mother Saraswati):
[image]

Picture of both of them closest that I got is this:

[image]

Now to Lord Vishnu:

[image]

Here is a relatively more close painting of the Lord and Mother Lakshmi(close in the sense that the above one shows Mother in a state of service,borne out of love,and is a/their Standard depiction,while the below one shows Mother more explicitly as arddhangini .)

[image]

Now Lord Shiva:

[image]

Although a good number of pictures depict Lord Shiva in a lone,meditative pose **when I search”Lord Shiva”**,the number of paintings that show a close
bond between Lord Shiva and Mother Parvathi is significantly higher ,*in that search itself*,as compared to the number of pictures showing Mother Lakshmi at Lord Vishnu’s feet,let alone as ardhangini when I search **Lord Vishnu**,and  that showing Mother Saraswati and Lord Brahma together/close ;*almost nil* when I search **Lord Brahma**.

Also,among the Trimurti,**only Lord Shiva** has a complete family(depicted along with  Himself.

**Is there any theological meaning that can be deduced from this/reason that explains this?**

Comment: 'Shiva' if you remove 'E' kaara from Shiva it becomes Shava.. thus it is 'Ekara' which transforms Shava to Shiva.. this is the relation of Shiva-Shakti (Ardhanarishwara rupa, Uma dehardha dharinam, Vaag artha Viva samprukta / word-meaning relation). Ganesha is gatekeeper of Shakti (in Kundalini sadhanas Ganapati is invoked) formed from body of Shakti and latter again given life by Shiva.. Kartikeya is Guha (the hidden), Shanmukha (with six faces) and DevaSenapati (commander of Daivic forces).. it is very difficult to get Shanmukha rahasya as he is Guha.. all these have very deep yogic meanings

Comment: @Tezz,I don’t understand what you’re trying to say.

Comment: I think these are all the expressions of the artist. Lord Ram, a Vishnu avatar, is known for the amount of love and respect her had for Goddess Sita, so much so that he took the ekpatni vrat. Moreover, while address Lord Vishnu, the name of Goddess Lakshmi always comes first - Lakshmi Narayan, Sita Ram etc. Lord Balaji has Goddess Lakshmi depicted in his heart. 
Regarding the family, Sri Suktam clearly mentions the children of Lord Vishnu and Goddess Lakshmi.

Comment: @curiousseeker Never knew about the Sri Suktam part.My point was not to question the love of Mahavishnu for Mother Lakshmi(or for that matter even Brahmaji),but to know if there is any higher reason behind the “expressions of the artist”.Something like “Wealth is at the command of Lord Vishnu “(denoted by the Mother at His feet)(I don’t know if the above example is an implied meaning of the said painting).Likewise I was expecting some implied meaning for Lord Shiva and Brahmaji.

Comment: @Amethyst- Ok, I understand your question. I don't know that reason. But another good example that comes to mind is how Goddess Lakshmi sits on Lord Narasimha's lap. This is seen in every photo and murti.

Comment: @curiousseeker Yes,I’ve seen that a couple of times...Things are interesting.By the way,what is the name of Mother Lakshmi in that avatar,as wife of Narasimha?

Comment: @Amethyst- As per Sripada Srivallabha Charitamrutam, her name is Chenchu Lakshmi.
https://sripada-srivallabha.org/_media/en/sripada_srivallabha_charitamrutam.pdf

Comment: @curiousseeker Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Tezz “Ganesha is gatekeeper of Shakti (in Kundalini sadhanas Ganapati is invoked) formed from body of Shakti and latter again given life by Shiva.. Kartikeya is Guha (the hidden), Shanmukha (with six faces) and DevaSenapati (commander of Daivic forces).. it is very difficult to get Shanmukha rahasya as he is Guha.. all these have very deep yogic meanings” <—— This is wonderful, thx for typing this comment 