# Symbolism Of Karthik Six Heads Birth Story

Tags: kartikeya, birth

Have heard the story of Karthik’s birth many many times with some variations, but the energy ball of Bholenath & Gauri gets split into six pieces each time.

I think Agni Dev carries, then Ganga, then gets split into six and the Kritika take care of the six, which become Karthik with six heads.

What is the symbolism of six heads of Karthik especially in birth story ?

Am reading some peculiar analysis of this when looking up online. I sort of get the kundalini explanation but not fully ?

Comment: Texx comment here (first one) was about some of the greater meanings of these birth stories : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46775/closeness-with-spouse-family-among-the-trimurti?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C67.7290